# multiple self.write() commands within Tornado handler

Tags: python, tornado

I've read about rendering content partially with multiple `self.write()` commands (eg first the header.html, page content and then footer.html). It works just fine, but the web page isn't displayed in the browser until the last command was processed.

I want to realize a status update output. Instead of reloading after every step I get

```
Result:
Step 1 processed.

Result:
Step 1 processed.
Step 2 processed.

Result:
Step 1 processed.
Step 2 processed.
Success.
```

on one page, what wouldn't be bad, but I have to wait until completion to see anything.

Is there a way to update the browser output after every step without implementing separate handlers for every step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to push the data to the client before you're finished, make a call to [`self.flush()`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.flush) after each [`self.write()`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write).